# Аннотация параметра функции в Python, если параметр - файл

Tags: python

У меня есть функция, которая создает и возвращает объекты на основе переданного в нее `csv` файла, к примеру такая:

```
def get_objects_list(csv_file: xxx) -> list:
    return list()
```

В функцию я передаю объект файла, полученного из менеджера контекста, и не знаю, как мне его *аннотировать*. Подскажите?

Comment: Под аннотацией Вы понимаете указание типа?

Comment: Ага.
Просто во всем скрипте типы указаны, и вот это место меня смущает

Comment: Тип, возвращённый `open()` – `_io.TextIOWrapper`

Comment: Вместо `list` лучше использовать `typing.List`, кроме того, прописать дженерики явно, к примеру `def get_objects_list(csv_file: typing.IO[str]) -> typing.List[str]: ...`. Ну и если функция возвращает, скажем, список `str` и `bytes` в зависимости от переданного файла, тогда `typing.AnyStr` вместо `str`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [typing.IO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.IO):

```
import typing

def get_objects_list(csv_file: typing.IO) -> list:
    return list(...)
```

---

из документации:

> Generic type `IO[AnyStr]` and its subclasses `TextIO(IO[str])` and
>   `BinaryIO(IO[bytes])` represent the types of `I/O` streams such as
>   returned by `open()`.